How to conditionally disable retries with WebSocket using RxJS in Angular?
Problem:
I have a SocketService that manages WebSocket connections to both a frontend and an admin servers. I need to use the retry operator to handle automatic reconnections if the WebSocket connection fails. However, I also need the ability to disable retries and close the WebSocket connection when needed.
With my current logic the retry logic seems to prevent the socket from closing properly. Even when I attempt to close the WebSocket connection, the retry mechanism continues to attempt reconnections, which causes the socket to remain open and the complete() method to not fully execute.
import { NextObserver, retry} from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { appSettings } from '@app/configs';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
import { ISocketResult } from '@shared/models';
import { LoggerService } from './logger.service';
import {
    webSocket,
    WebSocketSubject,
    WebSocketSubjectConfig
} from 'rxjs/webSocket';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
    constructor(private _logger: LoggerService) {}

    private isAdminSocketConnected = false;
    private isFrontendSocketConnected = false;
    private retryDelay = appSettings.socketRetryDelayMS;
    private WS_ADMIN_ENDPOINT = environment.adminSocketHost;
    private maxRetryAttempts = appSettings.socketRetryAttempts;
    private WS_FRONTEND_ENDPOINT = environment.frontendSocketHost;
    private _adminSocketSubject!: WebSocketSubject<ISocketResult | null>;
    private _frontendSocketSubject!: WebSocketSubject<ISocketResult | null>;

    
    public connect(): void {
        // Connect to the frontend socket if not connected or closed
        if (
            !this._frontendSocketSubject ||
            this._frontendSocketSubject.closed
        ) {
            this._frontendSocketSubject = this.createSocketInstance(
                this.WS_FRONTEND_ENDPOINT
            );
        }

        // Connect to the admin socket if not connected or closed
        if (!this._adminSocketSubject || this._adminSocketSubject.closed) {
            this._adminSocketSubject = this.createSocketInstance(
                this.WS_ADMIN_ENDPOINT
            );
        }
    }

    
    public close(): void {
        // Close the admin socket
        this._adminSocketSubject.complete();
        // Close the frontend socket
        this._frontendSocketSubject.complete();
    }

    
    private createSocketInstance(
        endpoint: string
    ): WebSocketSubject<ISocketResult | null> {
        const socketConfig: WebSocketSubjectConfig<ISocketResult | null> = {
            url: endpoint,
            openObserver: this.createOpenObserver(endpoint),
            closeObserver: this.createCloseObserver(endpoint),
            deserializer: (event: MessageEvent) => {
                try {
                    const data = JSON.parse(
                        event.data
                    ) as ISocketResult;
                    return data;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error during deserialization:', error);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };

        return webSocket(socketConfig).pipe(
            retry({ count: this.maxRetryAttempts, delay: this.retryDelay })
        ) as WebSocketSubject<ISocketResult | null>;
    }

    private createOpenObserver(
        endpoint: string
    ): NextObserver<Event | undefined> {
        return {
            next: (event) => {
                switch (endpoint) {
                    case this.WS_ADMIN_ENDPOINT:
                        if (!this.isAdminSocketConnected)
                            this.isAdminSocketConnected = true;
                        break;
                    case this.WS_FRONTEND_ENDPOINT:
                        if (!this.isFrontendSocketConnected)
                            this.isFrontendSocketConnected = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        this._logger.error(
                            `Unexpected WebSocket server at ${endpoint}. Unable to determine the source.`
                        );
                        return;
                }

                // Check if both sockets are connected
                if (
                    this.isAdminSocketConnected &&
                    this.isFrontendSocketConnected
                ) {
                    this._logger.info(
                        'Frontend and Admin sockets are connected to the WebSocket server!'
                    );
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private createCloseObserver(
        endpoint: string
    ): NextObserver<Event | undefined> {
        return {
            next: (event) => {
                switch (endpoint) {
                    case this.WS_FRONTEND_ENDPOINT:
                        if (this.isFrontendSocketConnected)
                            this.isFrontendSocketConnected = false;
                        break;
                    case this.WS_ADMIN_ENDPOINT:
                        if (this.isAdminSocketConnected)
                            this.isAdminSocketConnected = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        this._logger.warn(
                            `Unexpected WebSocket server at ${endpoint}.`
                        );
                        return;
                }

                // Check if both frontend and admin sockets are disconnected
                if (
                    !this.isAdminSocketConnected &&
                    !this.isFrontendSocketConnected
                ) {
                    this._logger.info(
                        `Frontend and Admin sockets are disconnected from the WebSocket server!`
                    );
                }
            }
        };
    }
}


The retry has a variation, where for the delay parameter we pass a function, this function retries when the return value emits, if it completes the retry stops, so we can use this concept here.
stopRetries = false;

stopRetriesFn() {
    this.stopRetries = true;
}

retryDelayFn() {
    // empty completes immediately, else timer will trigger the retry, along with a delay.
    return this.stopRetries ? EMPTY : timer(this.retryDelay);
}

return webSocket(socketConfig).pipe(
    retry({ count: this.maxRetryAttempts, delay: this.retryDelayFn.bind(this) }) // <- changed here!
) as WebSocketSubject<ISocketResult | null>;


Still its not working, on component load i am connecting the socket server, on a button click i want to close it by calling the close function.
In the close function i have set the stopRetries to true and in connect i have set the stopRetries to false, but still the log message in the CloseObserver not getting printed.

@RAHULKUNDU updated my answer!

@RAHULKUNDU when you manually close the websocket only, does the CloseObserver code get printed?

No that is the problem, when trying to close the server the retry operator is not letting me, if i remove the retry and than call the close function than the console Frontend and Admin sockets are disconnected from the WebSocket server! getting printed

with the updated code you have provided, its still happening. the CloseObserver is not getting called when calling the close function. The retry operator not letting the observables close and connects automatically, because of that CloseObserver is not executing.
